# SQL IS NULL check not giving correct result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: `mm_members`, `cmn_addresses`, `mm_member_statement_delivery_options`

In `mm_members`, I have columns -> `member_id`, `member_number`, `member_name`

In `cmn_addresses`,  I have columns -> `reference_id`, `reference_type`, `email`, `address`
and here `reference_id` is same as `member_id`

In  `mm_member_statement_delivery_options`, I have columns -> `member_id` , `statement_delivery_method`

I want all `member_numbers` who have `mm_member_statement_delivery_options`, `statement_delivery_method IN(2,3)` and in `cmn_addresses` they *do not have email and have reference_type = 3*

I have generated below query this is not getting the desired result

```
SELECT member_number FROM mm_members a 
JOIN mm_member_statement_delivery_options b ON a.member_id=b.member_id 
JOIN cmn_addresses c ON b.member_id=c.reference_id 
WHERE c.reference_type = 3
AND b.statement_delivery_method IN (2,3)
AND  (c.EMAIL IS NULL OR c.EMAIL = "");
```

Comment: I have also tried this query

Comment: SELECT member_number 
FROM mm_members ,mm_member_statement_delivery_options,cmn_addresses
WHERE mm_members.member_id = mm_member_statement_delivery_options.member_id
AND cmn_addresses.reference_id = mm_member_statement_delivery_options.member_id
AND mm_member_statement_delivery_options.statement_delivery_method IN (2,3)
AND cmn_addresses.reference_type=3
AND (cmn_addresses.EMAIL='' OR cmn_addresses.EMAIL IS NULL)
;

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: All those member numbers who don't have email in cmn_addresses but statement_delivery_method = 2 OR statement_delivery_method  = 3 in  mm_member_statement_delivery_options

Comment: is JOIN = INNER JOIN by default in mysql?

Comment: Yes JOIN is INNER JOIN.

Comment: You want c.email is null, or no matching record at all in c?  In this case, use left join instead of inner join.

Comment: Daniel can you give the query? if possible

Comment: Without your data and expected output, not easy.  But try this :
`SELECT member_number FROM mm_members a 
JOIN mm_member_statement_delivery_options b ON a.member_id=b.member_id 
LEFT JOIN cmn_addresses c ON b.member_id=c.reference_id 
WHERE c.reference_type = 3
AND b.statement_delivery_method IN (2,3)
AND  (c.EMAIL IS NULL OR c.EMAIL = "");`

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what is actually expected.

Comment: Ebenezar John Paul Need list of member_numbers  who don't have email in cmn_addresses but statement_delivery_method = 2 OR statement_delivery_method = 3 in mm_member_statement_delivery_options

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Daniel your query giving the same result as mine :/

Comment: Are you sure you have the data you believe you have? What happens if you for instance run the query without `c.reference_type = 3` or `b.statement_delivery_method IN (2,3)` (but add those columns to the output), do you get the expected result? Otherwise add some example input data to your question.

Comment: please put your data and result and expected result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hope it will work for you :)

SELECT 
DISTINCT mm_members.member_number AS MEMBER_NUMBER, 
TRIM(CONCAT(mm_members.first_name,' ',mm_members.last_Name)) AS MEMBER_NAME, 
cmn_addresses.email AS MEMBER_EMAIL, 
mm_member_statement_delivery_options.statement_delivery_method 
FROM mm_members 
JOIN cmn_addresses ON cmn_addresses.reference_id = mm_members.member_id AND cmn_addresses.reference_type = 3 
JOIN mm_member_statement_delivery_options ON mm_member_statement_delivery_options.member_id = mm_members.member_id 
WHERE (cmn_addresses.email IS NULL OR cmn_addresses.email = '') 
AND mm_member_statement_delivery_options.statement_delivery_method IN ('2','3') 
ORDER BY MEMBER_NUMBER;
```